# Akka actor(Scalia)l: how to react to the same message differently for different senders?

Tags: scala, akka

I am new to Akka and I am implementing something for fine. What I have now is a supervisor that have a child actor that does the actual work. If the work is done, the child will send the supervisor a case object Finished which changes the state of the supervisor.

However, in this sense, I can also send the supervisor in the master thread Finished, and then the action will be completely out of order.

Is there a way for the supervisor to react differently depending on who sends he message? Or better, it is possible to enforce the supervisor to only receive Finished if it is sent by its child?

Comment: You can find some solutions but, you probably shouldn't. Actors should not know anything outside their scope. You should encapsulate all behaviour and only react to messages, what about using different kinds of `Finished` messages? Just saying for example Finished for worker actors, Finish for supervisor actor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, quite easily.

Maintain set of children on supervisor actor:

```
 var children = Set[ActorRef]()
```

Wherever supervisor receives message, check if `sender` belongs to your set of children:

```
 def receive = {
    case Finished(_) if children.contains(sender) => ???
 }
```

That's it!

There is one thing to consider though, if you are using `Finished` for logically independent cases, think of creating different message types for each particular case.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Just a short question though, I am using a router for creating children, so in this case what will be the first line of code?

Comment: @RanWang, please update the question with the code that you have.